# Select IP in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, switch-statement

Im writing on a shell script to deploy my master-node.
To setup the node I would like to get a choice of available 
IP addresses the master should later listen on:

```
PS3='Please select a network the master should listen onto: '
ips=($(hostname -I))
select ip in "${ips[@]}"
do
    case $ip in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

But I run into "invalid option".
How can I properly select the IP from my list and use it further as variable at my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match digits. something like

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS3='Please select a network the master should listen onto: '
ips=($(hostname -I))
ips=("${ips[@]}" 'Quit')
select ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
  case $ip in
    *[0-9]*)
      echo "you chose choice $REPLY with the value of $ip"
      break
      ;;
    Quit) echo quit
      break;;
    *) echo Invalid option >&2;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I properly select the IP from my list and use it further as
>   variable at my script?

**This is a generic solution**: will work independently of the array content.

```
select ip in "${ips[@]}" "Quit"; do
  if [[ $ip = "Quit" ]]; then
    echo "Exiting ..."
    exit
  elif (( REPLY > ${#ips[@]} + 1 )); then
    echo "invalid option $REPLY"
  else
    break
  fi
done

echo "IP: $ip OPTION: $REPLY"
```

**Explanation**

The chosen option must not be greater than the number of elements in the IPs array plus the added exiting option.

**NOTE**: We're adding *Quit* to select options but not to the array so I will be *clean* for further use.